# Rhino and Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, rhino

I have written the code below, and it complains the the method "defineProperty" does not exist

```
#! /usr/bin/rhino

version(170)

function PrivScop(priv) {
        this.access
        Object.defineProperty(this, "access", {
                get: function () { return priv },
                set: function () { priv = arguments[0] }
                }
        )
}
var secret = new PrivScop(1)
```

Is define property not implemented in version 1.7 or not at all. Am I doing something else wrong? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.defineProperty` is defined in JS 1.8, which partially exists in Rhino 1.7R3, but is not enabled by default.  I'm not sure if `defineProperty` itself exists in 1.7R3, but if it does you need to set the langage version to `180`

Comment: I figured :-/ I got around it by using legacy getters and setters. Thank you

Comment: how to set the langage version to 180?